# How to add nginx modules to puppet manifest?

Tags: nginx, vagrant, puppet, puphpet, hiera

I need to install **Nginx** with some modules on my virtual machine (Debian 7 x64). I use **Vagrant** and one recipe from **Puphpet**. **Puphpet** uses **Hiera** to configure Vagrant and Puppet installation way. By default in **puphpet/config.yaml** I have nginx section:

```
nginx:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
    upstreams: { }
    vhosts:
        rpfrz3ldtf65m:
            proxy: ''
            server_name: awesome.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            www_root: /var/www/awesome
            listen_port: '80'
            location: \.php$
            index_files:
                - index.html
                - index.htm
                - index.php
            envvars:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            engine: php
            client_max_body_size: 1m
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
```

I need Nginx modules image_filter , so where could I place the correspond information in this config? I could place the Puppet manifect provided by puphpet configuring Nginx, but it's huge and too hard to understand.

Comment: can you provide a link to the nginx module that your using?

Comment: In my case the file is https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx/blob/v0.0.10/manifests/package/debian.pp

Answer (score 3):

Author of puphpet here.

From my understanding, Nginx needs to be compiled with your chosen modules, they cannot be enabled/disabled like Apache.

If the module you want is not installed in the Nginx package installed via puphpet, then that means it wasn't compiled in. You'll need to find another source that has that module compiled in, or compile Nginx yourself.

This is the Nginx Puppet module used in puphpet: https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx/tree/v0.0.10/manifests/package

Comment: Thanks, I added in package section (25 line) in **puphpet/puppet/modules/nginx/manifests/package/debian.pp** option: **install_options => [ '--with-http_image_filter_module', ],** . Unfortunately with no results. I cant see this module in modules list after **sudo nginx -V**